# how to create Touchstart event for custom Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, events, dom-events

On windows mousedown events works fine, and this code works perfectly and it is also adding "mousedown" event to a shape object.

```
    var shape = new Object();
    shape.mousedown(function(){
                alert('tracker move 2');
                this.paper.editor.action = "move";
              });
```

Also when I inspect in Chrome I get the following values.

**shape.events[0].name = "mouseDown";**

**shape.events.length = 1;**

But on iPad instead of mousedown I need to add touchStart event. Please guide me how to add this event. I tried different way but all are saying eventListener is basically used for DOM objects. Help me to achieve similar inspect values.
Note : I'm working on Safari browser in iPad.

Here is my sample code:

```
VectorEditor.prototype.showTracker = function(shape){
    var rot_offset = -14;
    var box = shape.getBBox();
    var tracker = this.draw.set();
    tracker.shape = shape;

    //define the origin to transform to
    tracker.lastx = 0 //if zero then easier
    tracker.lasty = 0 //if zero then easier

    if (mobilesafari) {
        var shapeTemp = this.markTracker(this.draw.ellipse(box.width/2, box.height/2, 7, 7).attr({
            "stroke": "gray",
            "stroke-opacity": 0.5,
            "fill": "gray",
            "fill-opacity": 0.15
        }));
        shapeTemp.addEventListener("touchstart", bind(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('tracker move 2');
            this.paper.editor.action = "move";
        }, this) ,false);
        alert(shapeTemp.events[0].name + " shapeTemp " + shapeTemp.events.length);
        tracker.push(shapeTemp);
    } else {
        var shapeTemp = new Object();
        shapeTemp.mousedown(function(){
            alert('tracker move 2');
            this.paper.editor.action = "move";
          });
        tracker.push(shapeTemp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried ?

Comment: @Rayon shape.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
    this.paper.editor.action = "move";
   });

Comment: And `error` in `console` ?

Comment: @Rayon addEventListener funtion is not defined.I suppose this error is expected as it is not a DOM object.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried in a fiddle or example ? Unable to make out...

Comment: @Rayon i have updated my sample code.mousedown event is getting registered with shapeTemp object successfully.